# Task not running using whenever gem but runs in terminal

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, whenever

**Task File**

```
require 'report.rb'
require 'rake'

    namespace :daily_report do
      desc "Daily Parakh Report"
      task daily_operator_report: :environment do
        puts "Daily report generation started"
        Reports::Report.generate_csv
        puts "finished"
      end
    end
```

**schedule.rb file**

```
set :environment, "development"

set :output, "home/rajdeep/police-api/log/whenever.log"

every 1.minute do # Many shortcuts available: :hour, :day, :month, :year, :reboot
  rake "daily_report:daily_operator_report"
end
```

nothing happens, the task doesn't run, even whenever.log file is not created.

when i run `rake daily_report:daily_operator_report` in terminal it works.

**UPDATE**
I checked my cron logs and found this 
`Nov 15 12:59:01 rajdeep-ThinkPad-T460s CRON[22125]: (rajdeep) MAIL (mailed 159 bytes of output but got status 0x004b from MTA#012)
Nov 15 13:00:01 rajdeep-ThinkPad-T460s CRON[22299]: (rajdeep) CMD (/bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/rajdeep/police-api && RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake daily_report:daily_operator_report --silent >> home/rajdeep/police-api/log/whenever.log 2>&1')
Nov 15 13:00:02 rajdeep-ThinkPad-T460s CRON[22298]: (rajdeep) MAIL (mailed 159 bytes of output but got status 0x004b from MTA#012)
Nov 15 13:01:01 rajdeep-ThinkPad-T460s CRON[22474]: (rajdeep) CMD (/bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/rajdeep/police-api && RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake daily_report:daily_operator_report --silent >> home/rajdeep/police-api/log/whenever.log 2>&1')
Nov 15 13:01:01 rajdeep-ThinkPad-T460s CRON[22473]: (rajdeep) MAIL (mailed 159 bytes of output but got status 0x004b from MTA#012)
Nov 15 13:02:01 rajdeep-ThinkPad-T460s CRON[22645]: (rajdeep) CMD (/bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/rajdeep/police-api && RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake daily_report:daily_operator_report --silent >> home/rajdeep/police-api/log/whenever.log 2>&1')
Nov 15 13:02:01 rajdeep-ThinkPad-T460s CRON[22644]: (rajdeep) MAIL (mailed 159 bytes of output but got status 0x004b from MTA#012)`

Initally it was giving me `info (No MTA installed, discarding output)` then installed MTA (without configuration, since i am not using any mailto).
I dont know what to make up of these logs. As stated above when i run `rake daily_report:daily_operator_report` the task works and csv file is generated but same is not happening when automated using whenever.

Comment: Have you tried to check whether your crontab file is generated properly by `bundle exec whenever`? If yes, have you updated it by `whenever --update-crontab`?

https://github.com/javan/whenever#the-whenever-command

Comment: Which OS are you using? Have you checked whether `cron` daemon is running there?

Comment: @Marian13 yes, i have updated it by `whenever --update-crontab` and i am using linux, and yes cron daemon is running too.

I verified it using `service cron status` and `ps -ef | grep crond`

Comment: @cnnr can you help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your crontab entry is correct. For 6:46PM, you should be getting

```
46 18 * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/rajdeep/police-api && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake daily_report:daily_operator_report --silent >> home/rajdeep/police-api/log/whenever.log 2>&1'
```

Whenever also defaults `RAILS_ENV` to `production`. To override this to say development, do

```
set :environment, "development"
```

at the top of the `config/schedule.rb` file

Don't forget to update your crontab by running `bundle exec whenever --update-crontab` and then confirm you have the correct crontab entry by running `crontab -l`

Comment: Hi actually that update was posted later and i had changed the time. Sorry for the confusion but the cronttab entry is correct, also i have changed the env to production as well. Still no effect. I will update my que with changed settings.